# how can i solve my Livebinding and combobox problem

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings

i have a dataset ( mysql ) bind with a combobox , i have seen a problem on it so i add a stringgrid to demonstrate the problem.

[image: Livebinding]

[image: Both combobox3 and stringgrid2 are linked]

when i click on XMPS combobox list is ok (combobox and stringgrid show same things )
[image: combobox ok]

when i click on XMPSSCO combobox and stringgrid show the single result , this is ok
[image: combobox ok]

but when i click on combobox , it list the previous data when stringgrid is correct
[image]

Has anyone faced this problem ?
What have i done wrong ?
Is this a bug ?

Thanks
Claude

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me in D10.4

Try **DropDownkind** property from the ComboBox. Change from Native to Custom.

```
TComboBox.DropDownKind = Custom
```

Only that. It works for me.
Ugly in android but you solve while you look for more options.

Alternatives: Woll2woll components or try in the new Delphi D11

Comment: Already confirmed, tested by me, that this problem is solved in version 11 alaxandria and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same pain in other forums.
Going through the TComboBox code, I found that livebindings doesn't trigger the Change event (for some reason);

Add a ComboBox.Items.Add(''); before the .execute of the dataset (this forcing the change event) and it works.

```
MyComboBox.Items.Add(''); //Force the trigger OnChange
MyDataSet.Execute;
```

I like this solution more than the previous one, because you keep the native mode.

I understand that it should be something provisional, but it is 1 line, and it solves this penalty for the moment.